# get list of Linked-In's available fields

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

How can I get list of all available fields(`Basic Profile Fields,Location Fields etc`) from `Linked-In REST API`.

Assuming my `Linked-In` APP has all permissions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn API documentation has a list of available fields/descriptions that you can request:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields

Assuming the user has authorized your app with LinkedIn you could do something like (in JS):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: ####
    authorize: true
    onLoad: getProfileData
</script>
```

---

```
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(last-name,first-name,positions)").result(onSuccess)
}

function onSuccess(data) {
    // do something with `data`
}
```

Comment: I mean, I need an API that list all available fields that I can use in request.In other words I need all fields name listed on 'https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields' page via REST API.